# Ruby: filter array by regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, filter

This is a common, repetitive idiom for me: filtering an array using a regular expression, and returning a sub-array. My approach doesn't seem very Ruby-like (I come from Java). I end up having many methods which look a lot like this.

What is the idiomatic Ruby way to improve this code?

```
def get_all_gifs(items_)
  output = Array.new
  filter = /\.jpg$/
  items_.each do |item|
    next if item =~ filter
    output << item
  end
  output
end
```

Comment: How are you getting the filenames? If from disk you can filter them when you retrieve the names using `Dir.glob('*.jpe?g')`

Comment: I think almost everybody misunderstood my question (perhaps because I asked it badly).  The example may be too loaded.  This isn't about images or filenames or file extensions.  It's about filtering of arrays, and a better idiom for methods to do that.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you want to find all gifs:

```
def get_all_gifs(files)
  files.select{ |i| i[/\.gif$/] }
end
```

If you want to find all jpegs:

```
def get_all_jpgs(files)
  files.select{ |i| i[/\.jpe?g$/] }
end
```

Running them:

```
files = %w[foo.gif bar.jpg foo.jpeg bar.gif]
get_all_gifs(files) # => ["foo.gif", "bar.gif"]
get_all_jpgs(files) # => ["bar.jpg", "foo.jpeg"]
```

---

But wait! There's more!

What if you want to group them all by their type, then extract based on the extension?:

```
def get_all_images_by_type(files)
  files.group_by{ |f| File.extname(f) }
end
```

Here's the types of files:

```
get_all_images_by_type(files).keys # => [".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg"]
```

Here's how to grab specific types:

```
get_all_images_by_type(files) # => {".gif"=>["foo.gif", "bar.gif"], ".jpg"=>["bar.jpg"], ".jpeg"=>["foo.jpeg"]}
get_all_images_by_type(files)['.gif'] # => ["foo.gif", "bar.gif"]
get_all_images_by_type(files).values_at('.jpg', '.jpeg') # => [["bar.jpg"], ["foo.jpeg"]]
```

Answer (score 25):

Have a look at [Enumerable.grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep), it's a very powerful way of finding/filtering things in anything enumerable.

Comment: This works like the dickens.  I'll probably use this from now on, but in a narrow sense, the "select" method is what I was after in this question.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, `grep` is great, in part because it uses `===` to compare elements of the receiver to `grep`'s argument. That allows you to write, for example,  `["abc", "bcd", "cbd"].grep(/.b./) #=> ["abc", "cbd"] ` and `[{a:1}, 4, {b:2}, "hat"].grep(Hash) #=> [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]`.

Answer (score 16):

```
$ cat foo.rb
images = %w[foo.gif foo.png foo.jpg bar.jpeg moo.JPG]
jpgs = images.select{|e| e =~ /\.jpe?g$/i}
puts jpgs.inspect

$ ruby foo.rb
["foo.jpg", "bar.jpeg", "moo.JPG"]
```

The change to your regexp is so that you can match "jpeg" in addition to "jpg" regardless of case.

Comment: The "select" method is what I'm looking for here (or rather the "reject" method, now that I've found it).  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

```
images = %w[foo.gif foo.png foo.jpg bar.jpeg moo.JPG]
images.grep(/.jpg/i) # => ["foo.jpg", "moo.JPG"]
```

Comment: oh come on Ruby sodlib team, we couldn't just call that `.match` also??

Answer (score 5):

We can go without *regex* for this specific problem. Use [`String#end_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F)

```
images = %w[foo.gif foo.png foo.jpg bar.jpeg moo.JPG]
images.find_all{|e| e.end_with?(".jpg",".jpeg")}
# => ["foo.jpg", "bar.jpeg"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ta, tb = files.partition{|f| f[/(.*\.jpe*g)/]}

ap ta
[
    [0] "bar.jpg",
    [1] "foo.jpeg"
]


ap tb
[
    [0] "foo.gif",
    [1] "bar.gif"
]
```

/gucio