# Does Ruby have a counterpart to the JavaScript array's filter method?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a quick way to filter an array in Ruby and am wondering whether the language has a counterpart to the filter method native to the JavaScrpt array object.

Comment: Out of curiousity, if you type "ruby array filter" into A Famous Web Search Engine, do you not get [this](http://xmlzoo.net/wiki/Ruby:Filtering_an_Array) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354864/ruby-filter-array-by-regex) or [this](http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/introduction-to-ruby---arrays) or any of several others within the first few results?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you have to read [ruby array documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html)

Comment: That said, I'm not seeing a good, simple duplicate of that question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yep. Even a Google search immediately turned up a bunch of stuff I didn't need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter an array by

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].select{|item| item == 'a'} # ["a"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[1,2,3].select do |i|
  i > 1
end
```

Comment: Refer to alex's answer to see how you mark up code on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has - [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select).

From documentation:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].select { |num|  num.even?  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  alias_method :select, :filter
end
```

Comment: A little description/explanation won't be bad with it.