# Matching string at the beginning, middle or ending of string

Tags: regex, ruby

Trying to write a regular expression that matches all the below:

```
LOREM X IPSUM
LOREM X
X IPSUM
```

where `X` is a word starting with L and ending with a digit (it may also include other Ls). I.e `LFCLL86A5`, `L00`.

`/.*\s(E\w+\d)\s.*/` works with the first option but I have a hard time making it work with the other two cases.

Comment: Use word boundaries, `\bL\w*\d\b`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Didn't know about word boundaries.

Comment: Also, do not use `.*` on both sides of the word matching pattern. Rather than that, split the text into lines and test for a match (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354864/ruby-filter-array-by-regex))